# How to validate url begins with a certain substring with Regexp (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I want to have a validation checking the image_url attribute always starts with

```
https://res.yakari.com/myapp/
```

Here is the current validation using Regexp I have

```
validates_format_of :image_url,
  :with => /\Ahttps:\/\/res.yakari.com\/myapp\/\S*\z/i,
  :message => "There's something wrong (doesn't begin with https://res.yakari.com/myapp, wrong path, white space inside string...)"
```

But it does not work, I have tested it and it rejects even the correct strings (those starting with https://res.yakari.com/myapp/)

How to do this ?

Comment: Please provide an example of the string it rejects. The regex seems to be OK.

Comment: Except that the `.` chars must be escaped to match literal dots. However, that is not a problem here. Just an idea: maybe the last `/` may be missing? Try `(\/\S*)?` instead of just `\/\S*`.

Comment: I'll add an example of string being rejected

Comment: My bad: the rejection was not due to the regexp but to a callback only acting on:update. I added to this validate on:update and it works. Sorry

Comment: should I delete the question?